# How to open up the overflow drain cover of a massage bathtub?

Tags: drain, bathtub

Our massage bathtub was installed by the previous owner.
I want to snake bathtub through the overflow drain to unclog the drain. But its cover is kind of unique. I couldn't find any instruction online.
[image: overflow drain cover]

Can anyone kindly shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A couple more pictures of that cover would be useful; if you can't edit the pictures into your question, edit in URLs and someone will be along to edit them in.

Answer (score 1):

Contact American Standard. I've seen images online that show they have tubs with this type of overflow. They should be able to advise you.
Also it looks as if you don't have any caulking around the edge of the tile joining the bathtub. It would be a really good idea to run some silicone caulking around that edge. Make sure it's silicone and you can get it in clear. If you're not used to using silicone it can be kind of messy when using it.

Comment: I found the documentation (http://www.americanstandard-us.com/assets/documents/amstd/install/Install_4475.pdf) and figured it out.  Basically, you can find the mounting screws under the protective tape.